# Small error in MongoDB update query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to update/add some variables to a set in MongoDB using Mongoose for awhile now but I just can't find the small error I'm having.

Can somebody see the error in my code, it's been driving me crazy and I haven't found the error and I'm in crunch time right now.

```
module.exports.findAndSubmitAttempt = function(annotationDate, annotationModule, annotationTitle, date, submission, studentID) {
    var query = {date:annotationDate,title:annotationTitle,module:annotationModule};    
    var updating = ClassAssignments.update(query, { $addToSet: {submissions: [ studentID, submission, date ] } }, {upsert:true}, function(err, doc) {
        if(err){
            console.log("Something went wrong uploading the submission");
        }
        console.log(doc);//This means everything works perfectly
    })
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(err)` ?

Comment: I suspect that the `submissions` is an array of object. is that right? If yes, then you are using array whereas you should use object in your above query. like: `submissions: { id: studentId, submission: submission, date: date }`.